# looking for a cleaner way to use scan in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

So I have seen one useful way of using scan where you map a function to the stream to update an initial value.

```
const initialState = false;
const notThis = (x) => !x;
const toggle = clicks.map(()=> notThis)
  .startWith(initialState)
  .scan((acc,curr)=> curr(acc))
```

But if I need the values from clicks I know I can write a partial

```
const initialState = {klass:'',bool:false};
const toggle = clicks
  .map((y)=> {
    return (x) => {
       let klass  = y.target.className;
       let bool = !x.bool;
       return ({klass, bool});
     };
  })
  .startWith(initialState)
  .scan((acc,curr)=> curr(acc));
```

This could be very useful if I am merging several streams, but it also seem like it could be overly complicated.  Is there a better way to accomplish passing data and functions down the stream?  Here is a bin of this example [link](https://jsbin.com/fefupexaxa/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should ask yourself if you need to pass down functions. I made your code a bit simpler:
https://jsbin.com/timogitafo/1/edit?js,console,output

Or an even simpler one: https://jsbin.com/giqoduqowi/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thank you for your feed back but the problem I posted was simple by design to illustrate a much complicated one where scan is holding state that is being merged from multiple streams.

Comment: Well I dont know about your problem, so I can't help you on that, but your solution with scan seemed very clever.